# Gradle multi-project does not generate Lombok's goodness

Tags: gradle, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have a multi-project in Gradle. The `build.gradle` script looks like:

```
buildscript {    
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.4"
    classpath "io.franzbecker:gradle-lombok:1.14"
  }
}

allprojects {
  //apply plugin: "base"
}

subprojects {
  apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.plugin-shadow"
  apply plugin: "idea"
  apply plugin: "java"
  apply plugin: "io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok"

  group = "io.shido"
  version = "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

  repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    // [start] Research
    //compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2"
    // [end] Research

    testCompile "nl.jqno.equalsverifier:equalsverifier:2.4.5"
    testCompile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junit_version"

    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:$junit_version"

    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junit_version"
  }

  //=================================================================================================
  //  P L U G I N S
  //=================================================================================================

  lombok {
    version = "1.18.2"
  }
  //=================================================================================================
  //  T A S K S
  //=================================================================================================

  // shadowJar { ... }

  test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
  }
}
```

I have a `messages` project then with this `build.script`:

```
plugins {
  id "java-library"
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
}
```

...and a `core` project with this `build.script`:

```
plugins {
  id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.6.RELEASE"
}

dependencies {
  compile project(":messages")
}
```

All of that should be OK.

If I write a simple class in `messages`:

```
package io.shido.event;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Builder
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "name")
class Prototype {
  private String id;

  private String name;
}
```

...and then a unit test for the same:

```
package io.shido.event;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

final class PrototypeTest {
  @Test
  void instantiate() {
    final Prototype event = Prototype.???
  }
}
```

I'm expecting I can use a builder for that class right there, but there is nothing generated.

Am I missing something in the setup? Everything compiles, but I can't see anything being generated for Lombok. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: Have you tried setting `sha256 = ""`? I'm not sure that completely omitting it will skip the integrity check.

Comment: Yes, but that didn't change the result. I also got rid completely of the `lombok { ... }` block, and now I'm getting by default `org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20` on `Provided` scope. I'm fine with any version, as long as it works initially. I can tweak the versions later on ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using IDEA and recent version of Gradle (I think >= 4.7) you could use the following setup which is working fine in my different projects:

1. install Lombok plugin for IDEA , from Settings->Plugins  configuration panel.
2. In your Gradle build script you can get rid of the lombok plugin declaration and lombok block : you just need to add the following dependencies on your project(s).

   ```
   ext{
       lombokVersion = '1.16.20'
       junitVersion = '4.12'
   }
   dependencies {
       compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
       annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
       // other libs ...

       // test dependencies
       testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: "${junitVersion}"
   }
   ```
3. After project re-import, make sure to enable Annotation Processing in IDEA, from *Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Compiler-> AnnotationProcessors* menu : there is a checkbox "*Enable annotation processing*" which is disabled by default.

This should work fine, and you'll be able to use Lombok features in your main code and in unit test as well.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work as stated in the [Lombok's guide](https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle), however it does work if I use your approach. I would really like to use the Gradle plugin (and I'll try later on), but  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Gaaaaaa.  the "disabled by default" was the answer for me.  Than you M.Ric!